# Laravel 5.1 file upload validation

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5.1

I want to upload an image file using

```
 {!! Form::open(['url'=>'admins']) !!}
  {!! Form::input('file','photo',null,['class'=>'photo_input']) !!}
```

Also my validation rules are

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
       'username'=>'required|max:127|min:3|unique:users,username,'.$this->username,
       'email'=>'required|max:127|email|min:3|unique:users,email,'.$this->email,
       'password'=>'required|max:127|min:5|confirmed',
       'password_confirmation'=>'required|max:127|min:5|',
       'role'=>'required|max:127|min:5|in:programmer,admin,employee',
       'photo' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,gif'
    ];
}
```

But I get an error

> The photo must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, bmp, png, gif.

Whereas the file extension which I choose is jpg, so what's wrong?

Comment: Where did you get this image file? It should have a mime type of jpeg, not only the file extension counts.

Comment: It's an common image file and I'm sure that it's mime type is jpg, also I tried other images but the result was the same.

Comment: Could you post the code for the entire html form? Or at least show us how you build the `form` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind is you need to define within your `form` tag the attribute `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`. So while using Laravel 5.X Form Facade you need to pass the attribute `files => true` within your array of `form open` like as

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'admins','files' => true]) !!}
                              //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ added
```

[**Source Docs**](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#file-input)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is also caused due to uploading large file size then the allowed in the php.ini

Please check

> upload_max_filesize

and

> post_max_size

in php.ini

You can also validate the Image size by extending the Validator

```
In Your Controller
Validator::extend('img_upload_size', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
 $file = Request::file($attribute);
 $image_size = $file->getClientSize();
 if( (isset($parameters[0]) && $parameters[0] != 0) && $image_size > $parameters[0]) return false;
 return true;
});


In Validation Rules
 return [
 'username'=>'required|max:127|min:3|unique:users,username,'.$this->username,
    'email'=>'required|max:127|email|min:3|unique:users,email,'.$this->email,
    'password'=>'required|max:127|min:5|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation'=>'required|max:127|min:5|',
    'role'=>'required|max:127|min:5|in:programmer,admin,employee',
 'photo' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|img_upload_size:1000000',//!MB
]
```

Comment: If this would be the case, wouldn't the web server return an error?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the reason was that I have not added enctype to the form.

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'admins','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
```

Comment: Thanks for all responses

Comment: The actual part to implement is using `{!! Form::open(['url'=>'admins','files'=>true]) !!}` instead of `{!! Form::open(['url'=>'admins','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}`